# Django - field missing from cleaned data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I am using model form and I'm trying to bypass validation of one particular field.

I have ascertained that I need use the clean() method to bypass the field. however when im printing out the cleaned data the assigned_subnets field is not in the dictionary, it is missing

actions:
I create the assigned subnet field manually in forms.py. Then using jquery I alter that form field and add more select options to it post all the options. The additional values posted were not part of the original field choices, hence the error.

output from print:

```
{'site_data': None, 'switches': None, 'hostname': 'STR--RTR-01', 'template': <ConfigTemplates: STR-RTR-01>, 'model': <DeviceModel: Cisco - 4431>, 'install_date': datetime.date(2016, 5, 26), 'ospf_area': None, 'snmp_data': <SNMPData: XXXX>, 'available_subnets': <QuerySet []>}
```

forms.py

```
    class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceData
        fields = ['site_data', 'switches', 'hostname', 'template', 'model', 'install_date','ospf_area','snmp_data']

    def clean(self):
        super(DeviceForm, self).clean()
        print(self.cleaned_data)
        if self.cleaned_data.get('assigned_subnets') in self._errors:
            del self._errors['assigned_subnets']
        return self.cleaned_data


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    site_id = kwargs.pop('site_id', None)
    device_id = kwargs.pop('device_id', None)
    self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
    super(DeviceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    devicesubnet = Subnets.objects.filter(devicesubnets__device_id=device_id)
    sitesubnet = Subnets.objects.filter(sitesubnets__site_id=site_id)
    common_subnets = list(set(devicesubnet) & set(sitesubnet))

    subnet_id_list = []
    for s in common_subnets: subnet_id_list.append(s.id)     
    available_subnet_data = sitesubnet.exclude(id__in=subnet_id_list)


    assigned_choices = []
    devicesubnet_data = DeviceSubnets.objects.filter(device_id=device_id)
    for choice in devicesubnet_data:
            assigned_choices.append((choice.subnet.id,choice.subnet.subnet))

    self.fields['available_subnets'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label='Available Subnets',
        queryset=available_subnet_data,
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(
            attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'size' : '15'}
        )
    )

    self.fields['assigned_subnets'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label='Assigned Subnets',
        choices=assigned_choices,
        widget = forms.SelectMultiple(
            attrs = {'class': 'form-control', 'size' : '15'}
        )
    )
    self.fields['available_subnets'].required = False
    self.fields['assigned_subnets'].required = False
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'device_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        ...
```

views.py

```
class EditDevice(UpdateView):
    model = DeviceData
    form_class = DeviceForm
    template_name = "config/device_form.html"

    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm('config.edit_device')))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.site_id = self.kwargs['site_id']
        self.site = get_object_or_404(SiteData, pk=self.site_id) 
        return super(EditDevice, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
            return reverse_lazy("config:device_details", args=(self.site_id,))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.site_data = self.site
        assigned_subnets = form.cleaned_data['assigned_subnets']
        print(assigned_subnets)
        return super(EditDevice, self).form_valid(form)


    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['site_id'] = self.site_id
        kwargs['device_id'] = self.object.pk
        return kwargs
    ...
```

**EDIT:**
what im trying to do is like in the image below. I have a list of available subnets and a list of chosen (assigned) subnets.
I don think this form widget exists outside of Django admin? so Ive created the two fields manually and used jquery to move a subnet from available to assigned.

then I get the assigned subnets and update the DB. however I get the errors when I alter the assigned field

[image: available to assigned]

Comment: Ive tried to remove all unrelated code and added additional description

Comment: How can `available_subnets` be in your `cleaned_data` when it isn't mentioned anywhere else in the code. Why do you need to change the choices in jQuery? Why can't you add those choices in the form?

Comment: sorry I removed that as unrelated code, ive put it back in and tried to add a better description and example of what im looking to achieve.

Comment: Which field is the game of thrones widget meant to be? `available_subnets` or `assigned_subnets`? Or are you using both fields to try to replicate the admin widget?

Comment: ive added a cap of the actual form instead of the GoT one. so currently I have two separate fields for this function, one field for available and one Feld for assigned. I then use jQuery to move an option from one field to another. is there anything built in that can do this without two fields?

Comment: I don't think that's a good design. You should have a single field to select subnets. It will make your Python code much cleaner. I'm afraid I can't help with how you get a widget similar to the `filter_horizonal` option in the Django admin.